# Stop folder recurse when

Tags: powershell, recursion

I'm trying to do the following -

```
$OutFile = "C:\temp\Audit_Permissions.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritanceFlags,PropagationFlags"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 

$RootPath = "\\netapp\DATA"

$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}

foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
    $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
    Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
    $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference  + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags
    Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
    }}
```

The problem is that about 3 or 4 levels deep into the folder structure I no longer need to do a recursive. There's the potential for thousands of folders in the format of yyyy\mm\dd which I want to ignore.  yyyy being the first folder.

so I want the audit on something like this -

```
\\netapp\data\folder1
\\netapp\data\folder2
\\netapp\data\folder2\folderA
\\netapp\data\folder3
\\netapp\data\folder3\folderA
\\netapp\data\folder3\folderA\testfolder
```

But as soon as it hits the following in any tree I want it to stop going further down -

```
\\netapp\data\folder3\folderA\testfolder\yyyy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to omit the foldername with yyyy.
You can adjust the RegEx part if you want to be more precise.

```
$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {($_.psiscontainer -eq $true) -AND ($_.FullName -notmatch '\\\d{4}($|\\)'}
```

Comment: I think you would have to match on `FullName` because he doesn't want to go into subfolders of 'yyyy'. `dir -Recurse -Directory | ? {$_.FullName -notmatch '\\\d{4}($|\\)'}`

Comment: hmmm...I'm more familiar with Python but I understand where you're coming from.  I've tried this though and it's still giving me all the yyyy or mm or dd folders.  I've tried basic stuff like -Contains '2015' to see if I could just get those folders to no luck.  It doesn't seem to be filtering is all I can gather.

Comment: changed the answer to reflect @dan-gph